# Automatically batch flipping and saving raster dataset under different name using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, modelbuilder, batch

I have 168 datasets, and I clearly cannot flip each one. I've tried batch processing but it is still time-consuming because I have to manually assign dataset and I/O path. I need something to do this automatically. I've tried ModelBuilder and so far I have this result:

[image]

The only problem with this one is that it overwrites the outputs and the result is only one dataset with the designated name. What I want is for each dataset, the result to be named accordingly (e.g Aprilie_2000 -> Aprilie_2000_flip and Aprilie 2001 -> Aprilie_2001_flip)

I am using ArcMap, how can I automate this process using ModelBuilder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried this model, using 4 rasters and %Name%_flip on the output, and it worked well.

[image]

In this case I chose the same geodatabase, but you can pick another one if you want.
[image]

Comment: Please check the answer if it worked for you, so we can track the answered questions...

Comment: @Cristina I suppose Rodri meant mark the answer as accepted so the question shows it is answered.

Comment: @Techie_Gus , new here, I don't really know all the rules, but thanks, marked it.